# ansible flipping inventory still reads in the same order

Tags: ansible

I am working on a project aimed at populating the IP's of some routers based on East/West locations.  The first host will always be the primary and the second will always be the secondary.

Based on the location passed, I flip the inventory.  I see the inventory being flipped, but Ansible get the value from the list in the same order.

It doesn't matter what order the inventory list is read.  I need for the first host to read the first element e.g. `20.21.22.23` and then the second host to read the second element `28.29.30.31`.

Right now, `ATL` is always the first element and `LAX` the second.

```
ok: [ATL_isr_lab] => {
    "msg": [
        "20.21.22.23",
        "24.25.26.27",
        "24.25.26.28"
    ]
}
ok: [LAX_isr_lab] => {
    "msg": [
        "28.29.30.31",
        "32.33.34.35",
        "32.33.34.36"
    ]
}
------------------ Inventory Flipped -------------------------------
ok: [LAX_isr_lab] => {
    "msg": [
        "28.29.30.31",
        "32.33.34.35",
        "32.33.34.36"
    ]
}
ok: [ATL_isr_lab] => {
    "msg": [
        "20.21.22.23",
        "24.25.26.27",
        "24.25.26.28"
    ]
}
```

```yaml
---
- hosts: test_hosts
  vars:
    region: east

    _Hub_IP: [ 20.21.22.23, 28.29.30.31]
    _Transit_IP: [ 24.25.26.27, 32.33.34.35]
    _Neighbor_IP: [24.25.26.28, 32.33.34.36]
    _idx: "{{ groups.all.index(inventory_hostname) }}"

  #flips inventory if west
  order: "{{ (region == 'east')|ternary('reverse_inventory', 'inventory') }}"
  become: yes
  ignore_unreachable: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks: 
  - name: "Configure Router"
    debug:
      msg:
        - "{{ _Hub_IP[_idx|int] }}"
        - "{{ _Transit_IP[_idx|int] }}"
        - "{{ _Neighbor_IP[_idx|int] }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working as posted originally. I had to upgrade to ansible version 2.11.6. I'm running Debian 10 and `apt-get update`/`apt-get upgrade` did not find a newer version.

My solution involved deleting the version and installing it again through pip.  After that, I ran the code and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is not coming with the `reverse_inventory` and `inventory` value of the `order` parameter like you seems to think it is.

The issue is to think that `groups.all` is indeed reversed when you do use the `reverse_inventory` value.

Here is an example of this, with the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  order: "{{ (region == 'east')|ternary('reverse_inventory', 'inventory') }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: groups.all
```

Running it with, with the region as an [`extra-vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime):

- `ansible-playbook play.yml --inventory inventory.yml --extra-vars "region=east"`
  Will yield:

  ```
  ok: [localhost] => 
    groups.all:
    - LAX_isr_lab
    - ATL_isr_lab
  ```
- `ansible-playbook play.yml --inventory inventory.yml --extra-vars "region=west"`
  Will yield:

  ```
  ok: [localhost] => 
    groups.all:
    - LAX_isr_lab
    - ATL_isr_lab
  ```

Still the sorting works, see:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  order: "{{ (region == 'east')|ternary('reverse_inventory', 'inventory') }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
```

Run with:

- `ansible-playbook play.yml --inventory inventory.yml --extra-vars "region=east"`
  Will yield

  ```
  ok: [ATL_isr_lab] => 
    msg: Hello world!
  ok: [LAX_isr_lab] => 
    msg: Hello world!
  ```
- `ansible-playbook play.yml --inventory inventory.yml --extra-vars "region=west"`
  Will yield

  ```
  ok: [LAX_isr_lab] => 
    msg: Hello world!
  ok: [ATL_isr_lab] => 
    msg: Hello world!
  ```

So, what ends up being wrong is your `_idx` value.
To fix this, you could use the [`reverse`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.reverse) filter of jinja with the same ternary as you are using in the `order` parameter, like this:

```yaml
_idx: "{{ ((region == 'east')|ternary(groups.all|reverse, groups.all)).index(inventory_hostname) }}"
```

---

Working playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  order: "{{ (region == 'east')|ternary('reverse_inventory', 'inventory') }}"

  vars:
    _Hub_IP: [20.21.22.23, 28.29.30.31]
    _Transit_IP: [24.25.26.27, 32.33.34.35]
    _Neighbor_IP: [24.25.26.28, 32.33.34.36]
    _idx: "{{ ((region == 'east')|ternary(groups.all|reverse, groups.all)).index(inventory_hostname) }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ _Hub_IP[_idx|int] }}"
          - "{{ _Transit_IP[_idx|int] }}"
          - "{{ _Neighbor_IP[_idx|int] }}"
```

Running examples:

- `ansible-playbook play.yml --inventory inventory.yml --extra-vars "region=east"`
  Will yield:

  ```
  ok: [ATL_isr_lab] => 
    msg:
    - 20.21.22.23
    - 24.25.26.27
    - 24.25.26.28
  ok: [LAX_isr_lab] => 
    msg:
    - 28.29.30.31
    - 32.33.34.35
    - 32.33.34.36
  ```
- `ansible-playbook play.yml --inventory inventory.yml --extra-vars "region=west"`
  Will yield:

  ```
  ok: [LAX_isr_lab] => 
    msg:
    - 20.21.22.23
    - 24.25.26.27
    - 24.25.26.28
  ok: [ATL_isr_lab] => 
    msg:
    - 28.29.30.31
    - 32.33.34.35
    - 32.33.34.36
  ```

Comment: I am getting the following error when I run the playbook: "{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: {{ ((region == 'east')|ternary(groups.all|reverse, groups.all)).index(inventory_hostname) }}: 'listreverseiterator object' has no attribute 'index'"

Comment: You're probably using an older Ansible version than mine, you should use `groups.all|reverse|list`, then, inside the ternary.

Comment: Still no luck:  my ansible version is 2.9.27and I  am using "_idx: "{{ ((region == 'east')|ternary(groups.all|reverse|list) }}""